# HQL not return results but when queried directly it works

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle11g, hql

I am trying below query in HQL but I get no results. Can someone help me on why I don't get any results? I tried to query the DB directly (please see SQL below) and i get 12 records. But HQL gives me 0 records.

"cause" I input the following String - "'XXX1','YYY 2'"

DB I use is Pracle 11g.

```
String queryStr = "from DefectsTran t join t.defects d where d.releaseName=:rel and t.defectCause in :cause and t.latestRecord=:lastrec"; 

Query q = session.createQuery(queryStr);
q.setString("rel", release);
q.setString("cause", filter2);
q.setString("lastrec", "Y");
```

SQL query that works fine when I use in TOAD.

```
select count(*) 
from QC10.defects_tran t
inner join QC10.defects on DEFECT_ID_FK_DT = RECORD_ID
where 
    DEFECT_CAUSE in ('Data Request Issue', 'Functioning as Expected', 'User Education Required', 'Test Script Incorrect', 'Test Specific')
    and t.latest_record = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `q.setString("cause", filter2);` use `q.setParameterList("cause", filter2);`. filter2 has to be of a `Collection` subtype. Please read more about other overloading available for setParameterList: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html

Comment: i tried this but i am still not getting any rows "List<String> filter12=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(filter2.split(",")));"

Comment: Please debug the SQL generated by hibernate by setting org.hibernate.SQL logger level to DEBUG. I'm sure there's a bug on your code somewhere

Comment: Thank you. There was an issue with my database data.